# How do I remove white space from around a body background image?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've used every trick in the poorly-documented book (bad joke pun intended) and there is still a white border around my background image. I am using Bootstrap but I've slapped `important` tags everywhere it counts, so I doubt that is what is causing the issue. If the issue can be resolved using Bootstrap 5, that would be great. I want to minimize the amount of CSS code I use in this project.

```css
html, body {
  background-image: url("./background.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

[Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e40s.png)

Comment: Does your reference image happen to have that white border?

Comment: @GeorgeSun No. I just double checked.

Comment: @WilliamFaircloth can you clear the browsercache? if that not works, it could be problems with other style declaration on your page.

Comment: it could be the aspect of your background image....can you try `background-size: cover;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `border` classname on the first div child of body. This adds a 1px solid border by default.

It's working even without your margin and padding set to 0!important in body since you have a _reboot css that already resets the body to margin 0.